# Sum Representation of log(1 + x)

Tags: calculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

$\log(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x}\right)^{k} \dfrac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{1+x}\right)^k \dfrac{1}{k}$

Why is this true? The most sum representation of $\log(1+x)$ (in this case a MacLaurin series) is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \dfrac{x^k}{k}$

Comment: The first expansion is not a power series in $x$ and so is not a Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 1):

From 
\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \, x^{k}}{k}
\end{align}
let $x = -u$ for which
\begin{align}
\ln(1-u) = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{u^{k}}{k}
\end{align}
Now let $u = \frac{x}{1+x}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \left( \frac{x}{1+x} \right)^{k}
\end{align}

Comment: great. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Differentiate the right-hand side term by term. We get a familiar series.  Note that there are restrictions on $x$.